# filter time from attendance log report using csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, filter

I have an employee's attendance log report in a csv file and i need to filter all the employee's attendances that were late (after 9:30).

I created a function that generated an attendance.  Employee enters his ID and the attendance is marked. the program gets date and time from computer clock, and stores the attendance in a log file.

```py
#function that generated an attendance 
def attandance_log():

    dnt =  datetime.datetime.now()
    dnt_string = dnt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    empid = input("Enter Your ID :")
    empname=input("Enter Your Name :")
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[dnt_string,empid,empname]],columns=["Today's Date & Time", "Employee's ID", "Employee's Name"])
    with open('/Users/sapir/Documents/python/final project- employee attandance log/attandance_log.csv', 'a') as f:
        df1.to_csv(f, header=False)
    return df1
attandance_df= attandance_log()

#the functions that filters all late attendances:
def late_emp_report():

    df = pd.read_csv('/Users/sapir/Documents/python/final project- employee attandance log/attandance_log.csv',index_col=0)
    #df[1] = pd.to_datetime(df[1], unit='s')
    # Add to employees list existing file
    #df.loc['29/07/2019 09:30:00': ].head()------->???
    #df_filtered = df[(df[1] <= datetime.time(9,30))]------>???

    print (df_filtered)
    with open('/Users/sapir/Documents/python/final project- employee attandance log/emplist.csv', 'w') as f:
        df.to_csv(f, header=False)
    return df


late_emp_report()
```

I have no idea how to create a file that shows all attendances after 9:30...

Answer (score 0):

You can apply filters in this form on the whole dataframe at once:

```
filtered_df = original_df[original_df[column_to_filter_on] > somevalue]
```

This will return a dataframe with all rows from original_df where the column value `column_to_filter_on` is greater than `some_value`

I prefer not using `1` as a column header and give it a name instead - to prevent later confusion with indexing.

You'll run into an issue when trying to compare a recurring time (9:30) vs a datetime, so instead, you can introduce a `late_flag` using `.apply()` to compare any datetime vs the 9:30 on that date.

```
# 'Initialize' datetime column in order to later grab df[1]
df['datetime'] = 0
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df[1], unit='s')

# Calculate late flag - compare datetime vs 9:30 on the same date for each row
df['late_flag'] = df['datetime'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x > x.replace(hour=9, minute=30, second=0, microsecond=0) else 0)

# Filter out just where late_flag is 1
df_filtered = df[df['late_flag'] == 1]
```

Comment: this is my csv fie

Comment: 0,29/07/2019 08:22:39,1,sapir
0,29/07/2019 08:31:14,2,gilad
0,29/07/2019 08:37:33,3,yarin
0,29/07/2019 09:38:02,1,sapir
0,29/07/2019 09:59:22,2,gilad
0,29/07/2019 10:22:39,3,yarin
0,29/07/2019 10:31:14,1,sapir
0,29/07/2019 10:37:33,2,gilad
0,29/07/2019 10:38:02,3,yarin
0,29/07/2019 10:59:22,1,sapir

Comment: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2890, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 1

Comment: Seems the error is from `df[1]` - see my edited answer for potential fix

Comment: i fixed as you suggested, but still it gives error.